# how to check whether image is 8 bit or 16 bit?

Tags: java

i m making APP which do image proceesing using java SE.i want to check programeticly at run time that whether image is 8 bit or 16 bit? and then according that i do image processing on that.so, how can i check it in java?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could start reading about Image Formats [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_format). In particular the section about Image File Sizes

Comment: i read that, but it not exactly solution of my problem.i only want to check whether the image is 8 bit or 16 bit at run time in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is post here that is trying to read a 8-bit and 24-bit bmp file.
 http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip43.html?page=2

Here it tries to get the number of bits like this:

```
int nbitcount = (((int)bi[15]&0xff)<<8) | (int)bi[14]&0xff
```

Once you get this count you can validate this what type of image it is based on this bit count.

Comment: is there any method direct to check BufferedImage type? means whether is 8 bit image or 16 bit image?

Comment: Is ther any other method or solution for checking bit of image?

Comment: refer this link in JAI (Java Advanced Image).http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/6.0-JDK-Modules/Java-Advanced-Imaging/com/sun/media/jai/codec/TIFFField.java.htm. And this class has a getType() and getASBytes() methods.try this

Comment: thank u foe help to me, i will try this method in my program.

Answer (score 1):

If you read in the image as a `BufferedImage`, you can use the [`getType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType%28%29) method.

Comment: i check this method , but it cant work exactly,please give me other solution